# Biblatex ieee incorrect display of volume and issue number

Tags: biblatex, article

When compiling a tex file including references (by Texstudio editor and Miktex distribution) using biblatex with bibtex backend and ieee style, the results of the displayed references in the output pdf is messed up at the "volume" and "issue number" entries as follows:

1. The volume label "vol." is missing (Ref. 1 & 2 in the given example below).
2. The numeric issue number "3" is missing (Ref. 1 in the given example).
3. The issue number label "no." is displayed although NO input entry was being given (Ref. 2 in the given example).

If it helps, this behavior was noticed after the recent update of Miktex on March 11, 2017, including [biblatex-ieee](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) package (ver. 1.2a 2017-03-02). As before which, everything was going fine!

So is this issue noticed by someone else? Is there any idea about the reason of such strange act by biblatex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
    @article{author1,
        author  = "George Green",
        title   = "Basic latex",
        year    = "2000",
        journal = "Sharelatex Journal",
        volume  = "10",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "100--101"
    }
    @article{author2,
        author  = "Carol White",
        title   = "Basic studio",
        year    = "2010",
        journal = "Club Journal",
        volume  = "20",
        pages   = "200--201"
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
    Hi there! \\
    Ref 1 Green \cite{author1}. \\
    Ref 2 White \cite{author2}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:
[image: with]

Comment: I've recently refactored the code here: it's quite possible I've messed up somewhat!

Comment: @JosephWright `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}` has `\bibstring{number}` where you probably want `\printfield{number}`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and your efforts in developing latex and many useful packages. I'm afraid I am not familiar with programming terminologies (refactored) so what should I do now? Wait for next miktex package update or manually download the package?

Comment: @JosephWright, I am glad to see the Biblatex-ieee update 1.2b 22/3/2017 appearing this soon on citan (not reflected on miktex updates yet). However, i had a look on the updates 1.2b pdf documentation, i noticed the issue no. label and numerals are now displayed ok but the volume label (vol.) might still be missing as shown in Ref. 5 (Castaldini et al 1997: perhaps vol. 56) when the  vol. and no. entries are combined. I might be wrong though because I didn't compile yet.

Comment: @hesham I'll look at that

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for the 1.2 c update. Vol. and issue numbers numerals and labels seems perfect in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1.2a `biblatex-ieee`'s a line in the macro `volume+number+eid` erroneously read `\bibstring{number}` instead of `\printfield{number}`. The correct definition is

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
```

which you can just put into your preamble.

You also need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace#1}
```

for the 'vol.' before the volume.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for the temporary fix. I will try it and tell you later about it. Written by you, of course i dont suspect it's going to work!

Comment: Dear @moewe, your fix has worked as expected. I will be looking forward to the next release of biblatex-ieee. Thanks.